# How to Split Comment over Multiple Lines in Math-mode

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, minipage

In a proof, I want to split the equations on the left and have a picture on the right using minipages. However for one of the equations on the left, the comment is too long and is too big for the minipage. How can I split the comment so that it goes across two lines? I understand it can be done equations, but not sure how to do it for comments. Below is my code and the output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}~\\
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
AB = BD, & AC=CE &\qquad &\textrm{(midpoint of a side)}\\
\angle BAC &= \angle DAE&\qquad &\textrm{(common angle)}\\
\frac {AB}{AD} &= \frac {AC}{AE} = \frac 12\\
\therefore \Delta ABC &\sim \Delta ADE& \qquad &\textrm{(SAS; 1:2)}\\
\angle ABC & = \angle ADE& \qquad &\textrm{(matching $\angle$ 's, $\Delta ABC \sim\Delta ADE$)}\\
\therefore BC &\| DE& \qquad &\textrm{(corresponding $\angle$'s are $=$)}\\
\frac{BC}{DE} &=\frac 12 & \qquad & \textrm{(matching sides in the same ratio,$\Delta ABC \sim\Delta ADE$)}\\
\therefore BC &= \frac 12 DE && \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{proof.PNG}
\end{minipage}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As in the above diagram, I want to split the comment at the vertical line and place it on the next line aligned with the other comments.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: i'd try using a `\parbox` for that comment.  sorry, i can't test now -- no available latex installation -- but i'll try to do so tomorrow (unless someone else gets here first).  by the way, the qed box is in a really peculiar location; i think that `\qedhere` has probably never been tested inside a `minipage`.  i'll take a look at that too,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way, using  `alignat*` instead of `align*`, `aligned`for the longest comment, and `adjustbox` to control the vertical alignment of the image. Note you don't have to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`. I also slightly simplified your code (needless to add `\qquad` on each line):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness} {0.3pt}
\usepackage[demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}~\\[-3ex]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
AB = BD&,\; AC=CE & \quad &\textrm{(midpoint of a side)}\\
\angle BAC &= \angle DAE& &\textrm{(common angle)}\\
\frac {AB}{AD} &= \frac {AC}{AE} = \frac 12 & & \\
\therefore \Delta ABC &\sim \Delta ADE&&\textrm{(SAS; 1:2)}\\
\angle ABC & = \angle ADE& &\textrm{(matching $\angle$ 's, $\Delta ABC \sim\Delta ADE$)}\\
\therefore BC &\| DE& &\textrm{(corresponding $\angle$'s are $=$)}\\
\frac{BC}{DE} &=\frac 12 & & \begin{aligned} & \textrm{(matching sides in the same ratio,}\\%
& \Delta ABC \sim\Delta ADE)\end{aligned}\\
\therefore BC &= \frac 12 DE & & \qedhere
\end{alignat*}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\smash{\adjincludegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,valign = t, raise = -.25\totalheight]{proof.PNG}}
\end{minipage}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following solution uses `\parbox` directives to permit line breaks in three of the explanatory remarks. The width of each `\parbox` is set to the length of the string `(midpoint of a side)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{article} % remove 'draft' in real doc.
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsthm}

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{(midpoint of a side)}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\parbox[t]{\mylength}{\raggedright #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}~\newline
\begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
AB = BD, & AC=CE &\quad &
        \text{(midpoint of a side)}\\
\angle BAC &= \angle DAE &&
        \text{(common $\angle$)}\\
\frac {AB}{AD} &= \frac {AC}{AE} = \frac 12\\
\therefore \Delta ABC &\sim \Delta ADE &&
        \text{(SAS; 1:2)}\\
\angle ABC & = \angle ADE &&
        \mybox{(matching $\angle$\,s, 
               $\Delta ABC \sim\Delta ADE$)}\\
\therefore BC \,&\|\,DE &&
        \mybox{(corresponding $\angle$\,s 
               are $=$)}\\
\frac{BC}{DE} &=\frac 12 && 
        \mybox{(matching sides in the same ratio, 
               $\Delta ABC \sim\Delta ADE$)}\\
\therefore BC &= \frac 12 DE && \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{proof.PNG}
\end{minipage}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```